# What should be the first step to move Angular?

Tags: angular

I want to now start increase knowledge in Angular. So,any body have suggestion what should be my first step to start angular.

Comment: I would prefer reading all pages of http://angular.io/ with practical, It contains explanation in depth

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [sample application](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard/angular) for Angular with google appengine. It includes how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

How I started (already have a little Angularjs experience):

[Typescript in 5 minutes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html)

[Typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html)

[Angular "Tour of heroes"](https://angular.io/tutorial)

[Angular fundamentals](https://angular.io/guide/architecture)

And then just developing and googling what I need. Quite simple, but this way wasn't really hard, because you have SO and a couple of good articles about Angular technology. If you don't know ES6 (especially classes), take a look on this specification, it's important.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's website has a lot of good documentation to start learning it. This is the order I would follow:

- [Angular QuickStart](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)
- [Angular Tutorial (Tour of Heroes)](https://angular.io/tutorial)
- [Angular Fundamentals](https://angular.io/guide/architecture) (it has several sections, ensure you check them all, if you did the QuickStart first then the concepts of this page should already be familiar)

After completing those 3, start doing an application for yourself from scratch using [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) (the CLI is used in the Tutorial so you'll already know it by then). This will give you real hands-on experience.

**Only after** you have finished all of the above:

- [Angular Testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing) (this one is heavy)